# Caps lock doesn't work on lock screen with the English (Macintosh) keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, lock-screen

When typing in my password, the caps lock button does not work.  The shift key does work.

**Here is a detailed description of the problem:**

- This is only true for the "English (Macintosh)" keyboard.  If I use "English (US)" or "English (UK)", the caps lock key works.
- This is only true on the lock screen; using caps lock in "English (Macintosh)" works once logged in; for example I can use it while typing this question.
- Caps lock is failing for characters in the English alphabet, such as A and B.

**Here is some information about my Ubuntu version:**

- OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
- OS Type: 64-bit
- GNOME Version: 3.36.8
- Windowing System: X11

**Attempted solutions**

I have tried finding the answer to this online; I am not alone in finding strange caps lock behavior but the questions are typically about non-English-language characters.  I found [this thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1750336) with a similar problem that was caused by an NVIDIA driver I do not possess.  Some [lock-screen-input problems](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1566357) seem to be caused by the keyboard input method.

One feature of the "English (Macintosh)" keyboard is how easy it is to type accent marks.  In the second thread I linked, one of the participants had trouble using a Korean keyboard.  This leads me to think that perhaps the issue arises when the keyboard allows compositional characters?

**Solutions?**

The use of the "English (Macintosh)" keyboard is important to me, because of the ease with which I can type mathematical symbols (∑≈√∫) and accent marks (éîêö).  I am very familiar with these shortcuts and don't want to change to a new keyboard.  Thus, I am looking for either a solution that fixes the caps lock problem on login for this keyboard or an alternative keyboard that contains the same shortcuts but does not have this problem.

My current workaround is to swap to a different keyboard just for login.  I suppose I could use shift instead of caps lock, but where's the fun in that?

## Edit:

Caps lock fails on any prompt requiring me to input my system password.  It also fails on the terminal on Visual Studio Code, but curiously not the terminal from the actual Terminal app.

Comment: I have found that English (UK, Macintosh) works, but the mapping to the special symbols is different and it does not have the symbols I want :/